# Array Merge with array value as key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I am trying to convert an multi-dimentional array of product data where the PayPal email is set as one of the array values(can be same for some). I need help on merging those as arrays where the paypal_email key is same. Here is the `print_r` of the array that I have.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Test Product
            [product_id] => 307
            [variation_id] => 0
            [subtotal] => 30
            [total] => 30
            [quantity] => 2
            [subtotal_tax] => 2.66
            [total_tax] => 2.66
            [paypal_email] => thisismytestpaypal@sandbox.com
            [vendor_id] => 2
            [shipping] => Array
                (
                    [shipping_total] => 25.00
                    [shipping_tax] => 2.22
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Album
            [product_id] => 354
            [variation_id] => 0
            [subtotal] => 15
            [total] => 15
            [quantity] => 1
            [subtotal_tax] => 1.33
            [total_tax] => 1.33
            [paypal_email] => thisismytestpaypal@sandbox.com
            [vendor_id] => 11
            [shipping] => Array
                (
                    [shipping_total] => 25.00
                    [shipping_tax] => 2.22
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Beanie with Logo
            [product_id] => 357
            [variation_id] => 0
            [subtotal] => 18
            [total] => 18
            [quantity] => 1
            [subtotal_tax] => 1.60
            [total_tax] => 1.60
            [paypal_email] => ab2@sandbox.com
            [vendor_id] => 10
            [shipping] => Array
                (
                    [shipping_total] => 25.00
                    [shipping_tax] => 2.22
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Long Sleeve Tee
            [product_id] => 352
            [variation_id] => 0
            [subtotal] => 75
            [total] => 75
            [quantity] => 3
            [subtotal_tax] => 6.66
            [total_tax] => 6.66
            [paypal_email] => ab2@sandbox.com
            [vendor_id] => 2
            [shipping] => Array
                (
                    [shipping_total] => 25.00
                    [shipping_tax] => 2.22
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Polo
            [product_id] => 353
            [variation_id] => 0
            [subtotal] => 80
            [total] => 80
            [quantity] => 4
            [subtotal_tax] => 7.10
            [total_tax] => 7.10
            [paypal_email] => tv3@sandbox.com
            [vendor_id] => 8
            [shipping] => Array
                (
                    [shipping_total] => 25.00
                    [shipping_tax] => 2.22
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => Product From Test Vendor 3
            [product_id] => 145
            [variation_id] => 0
            [subtotal] => 60
            [total] => 60
            [quantity] => 3
            [subtotal_tax] => 5.33
            [total_tax] => 5.33
            [paypal_email] => tv3@sandbox.com
            [vendor_id] => 10
            [shipping] => Array
                (
                    [shipping_total] => 25.00
                    [shipping_tax] => 2.22
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => Product From Vendor 1
            [product_id] => 143
            [variation_id] => 0
            [subtotal] => 20
            [total] => 20
            [quantity] => 2
            [subtotal_tax] => 1.78
            [total_tax] => 1.78
            [paypal_email] => tv1@sandbox.com
            [vendor_id] => 8
            [shipping] => Array
                (
                    [shipping_total] => 25.00
                    [shipping_tax] => 2.22
                )

        )

)
```

I need the array to merged as a multi-dimentional array with the paypal email as key and other data as values.. For example,

```
Array
(   [thisismytestpaypal@sandbox.com] => Array
        (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Test Product
                [product_id] => 307
                [variation_id] => 0
                [subtotal] => 30
                [total] => 30
                [quantity] => 2
                [subtotal_tax] => 2.66
                [total_tax] => 2.66
                [paypal_email] => thisismytestpaypal@sandbox.com
                [vendor_id] => 2
                [shipping] => Array
                    (
                        [shipping_total] => 25.00
                        [shipping_tax] => 2.22
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Album
                [product_id] => 354
                [variation_id] => 0
                [subtotal] => 15
                [total] => 15
                [quantity] => 1
                [subtotal_tax] => 1.33
                [total_tax] => 1.33
                [paypal_email] => thisismytestpaypal@sandbox.com
                [vendor_id] => 11
                [shipping] => Array
                    (
                        [shipping_total] => 25.00
                        [shipping_tax] => 2.22
                    )

            )
        )

    [ab2@sandbox.com] => Array
        (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Beanie with Logo
                [product_id] => 357
                [variation_id] => 0
                [subtotal] => 18
                [total] => 18
                [quantity] => 1
                [subtotal_tax] => 1.60
                [total_tax] => 1.60
                [paypal_email] => ab2@sandbox.com
                [vendor_id] => 10
                [shipping] => Array
                    (
                        [shipping_total] => 25.00
                        [shipping_tax] => 2.22
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Long Sleeve Tee
                [product_id] => 352
                [variation_id] => 0
                [subtotal] => 75
                [total] => 75
                [quantity] => 3
                [subtotal_tax] => 6.66
                [total_tax] => 6.66
                [paypal_email] => ab2@sandbox.com
                [vendor_id] => 2
                [shipping] => Array
                    (
                        [shipping_total] => 25.00
                        [shipping_tax] => 2.22
                    )

            )
        )

    [tv3@sandbox.com] => Array
        (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Polo
                [product_id] => 353
                [variation_id] => 0
                [subtotal] => 80
                [total] => 80
                [quantity] => 4
                [subtotal_tax] => 7.10
                [total_tax] => 7.10
                [paypal_email] => tv3@sandbox.com
                [vendor_id] => 8
                [shipping] => Array
                    (
                        [shipping_total] => 25.00
                        [shipping_tax] => 2.22
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Product From Test Vendor 3
                [product_id] => 145
                [variation_id] => 0
                [subtotal] => 60
                [total] => 60
                [quantity] => 3
                [subtotal_tax] => 5.33
                [total_tax] => 5.33
                [paypal_email] => tv3@sandbox.com
                [vendor_id] => 10
                [shipping] => Array
                    (
                        [shipping_total] => 25.00
                        [shipping_tax] => 2.22
                    )

            )
        )
    [tv1@sandbox.com] => Array
        (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Product From Vendor 1
                [product_id] => 143
                [variation_id] => 0
                [subtotal] => 20
                [total] => 20
                [quantity] => 2
                [subtotal_tax] => 1.78
                [total_tax] => 1.78
                [paypal_email] => tv1@sandbox.com
                [vendor_id] => 8
                [shipping] => Array
                    (
                        [shipping_total] => 25.00
                        [shipping_tax] => 2.22
                    )

            )
        )

)
```

How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @NigelRen, yes I did. There was so many approaches that I lost track :(

Comment: @Abhik, I know the feeling, but non-demonstration of effort leads to negative voting on SO, as it reads: code this for me.

Comment: @Progrock, that was not the intention mate, just lost the track of the tries.

Comment: @Abhik, I'm sure it wasn't your intention, just warning you, as your question may be downvoted or even closed :)

Comment: please remember to mark your question as solved if it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$orders = [.....]; //your array
$mappedOrders = [];
foreach($orders as $order) {
    $mail = $order['paypal_email'];
    if(!isset($mappedOrders[$mail])) { $mappedOrders[$mail] = []; }  //create new array in map if $mail index not exists
    $mappedOrders[$mail][] = $order;  // push order into array for mapped array
}

var_dump($mappedOrders);
```

Answer (score 3):

Do a loop with array key checking

```
$result = [];

foreach ($array as $value) {
    $email = $value['paypal_email'];          // Get email

    if (!array_key_exists($email, $result)) { // Check if already on the result array
        $result[$email] = [];                 // Create new array with email as key if not
    }

    $result[$email][] = $value;               // push value to email key
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: hihi almost same answer... upvote of course

in this case it doesnt matter if array_key_exists or isset...

Comment: No need to check and initialise an empty array for non existing keys.

Comment: actually you are right progrock - there's no need for it in PHP.. but its better codestyle and easier to adapt that logic to other programming languages

Comment: @Kapsonfire what have other programming languages got to do with anything?

Answer (score 1):

Consider first array hold by variable `$array`. Then iterate it with simple `foreach` loop and transfer data to new array `$newArray` with key as value in `paypal_email` node. Code should be:

```
$newArray = [];

foreach ($array as $value) {
    $newArray[$value['paypal_email']][] = $value;
}
print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: won't work since  an index may have for than one entry.. so you need an array

Comment: @Kapsonfire they fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$data = 
[
    [
        'name' => 'John',
        'email' => 'thebeatles@example.com'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Ringo',
        'email' => 'thebeatles@example.com'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Mick',
        'email' => 'thestones@example.com'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Keith',
        'email' => 'thestones@example.com'
    ],
];
$grouped_by_email = [];
foreach($data as $item)
    $grouped_by_email[$item['email']][] = $item;

var_export($grouped_by_email);
```

Output:

```
array (
    'thebeatles@example.com' => 
    array (
    0 => 
    array (
        'name' => 'John',
        'email' => 'thebeatles@example.com',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
        'name' => 'Ringo',
        'email' => 'thebeatles@example.com',
    ),
    ),
    'thestones@example.com' => 
    array (
    0 => 
    array (
        'name' => 'Mick',
        'email' => 'thestones@example.com',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
        'name' => 'Keith',
        'email' => 'thestones@example.com',
    ),
    ),
)
```